# Specify an SVG as a background image and ALSO style the SVG in CSS?

Tags: css, svg

Is it possible to specify an SVG as a background image and ALSO style the SVG in the same CSS file?

I'm very comfortable placing, scaling and clipping SVG images as either single files or sprites, but I haven't been able to work out if it possible to style the SVG within the same CSS file as sets it as a background image.

In pseudo CSS i'd like to do the following to vary the colour of simple shape based on the class of the parent element:

```
element1 {
 background-image(icon.svg);
}

element1.black .svg-pathclass {
 fill: #000000;
}

element1.white .svg-pathclass {
 fill: #ffffff;
}
```

obviously this assumes a path in the SVG having class .svg-pathclass

is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The SVG has to be prepared in one document (which may be a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) or an externally referenced file) and *then* used as a background in another file.

Comment: @joneb I don't think it would be neat, I think it would cause circular reference problems. :)

Comment: yes, you are right. the use of neat in this instance is related to: "I wish it work for the purpose i have right now in the absence of considering the wider implications" :D

Comment: @JSDBroughton #WhyDontTheyJust…

Answer (score 6):

You can use `SVG` and `CSS` masks to recreate this effect, then use normal `CSS` to style the inside of the `SVG`, even `background-image`

```
-webkit-mask:   url(filename.svg) 50% 50% / 100px 50px no-repeat;
    -o-mask:    url(filename.svg) 50% 50% / 100px 50px no-repeat;
    -ms-mask:   url(filename.svg) 50% 50% / 100px 50px no-repeat;

background-color: red;
background-image: url(animated.gif);

/* Filename, Position / Size, Repeat */
/* Modernizr.cssmask is the test needed to pass - snippet below */
```

You can use this to create drop shadows by appending an `element` to the `DOM` and styling that, with a lower z-index and setting an opacity.

Hope that helps!

Edit: Links

- Modernizr Test - http://pastebin.com/w4eVbEKr
- Some more information - https://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/

Comment: unless -o and -ms not exist :/

Comment: This would be neat, may not work, depending on how complex the image is & it is not supported by all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually possible for those who can use preprocessors in production, by "inlining" background SVG, and bit of SASS `mixins`, which "slice" whole `svg` gibberish, to get access to parts you want to manipulate via `SASS variables`.

In your original scenario you have an element
`<div class="element1"></div>`,

so you need a `mixin/function` which will inline SVG for you. Let's say you want to control of the `fill`, so:

```
@mixin inline-svg($color, $svg-content) {
  $start: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><style>path { fill:#{$color}; }</style>';
  $end:   '</svg>';

  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, #{$start}#{$svg-content}#{$end}');
}
```

where `$svg-content` variable is your `<svg>` stuff excluding `<style>` element (which you want to access from inside of the `mixin`) and wrapping `svg` tag,, ie:
`$svg-content = "<path .... />"`

This just need to be included with values passed inside:
`@include inline-svg(salmon, $svg-content);`

To sum whole thing up, this is an example **SASS** code:

```
$svg-content = "<path .... />"

@mixin inline-svg($color, $svg-content) {
    $start: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><style>path { fill:#{$color}; }</style>';
    $end:   '</svg>';

    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, #{$start}#{$svg-content}#{$end}');
}  

.element1 {
    @include inline-svg(rgba(0,0,0,0.6), $svg-content);
}
```

I think possibilities here are quite big (there are also limitations here to that approach). I actually pass a `SASS map` to my `mixin` with `css` styles defined as `key`, `value` pair, to inject whole bunch of `css` styles to the `<style>` part of `svg`.

So it's technically possible, but require more compexity, but once you get this done, you'll get benefits of reusing this `mixin` throughout your project(s), which is cool .

Comment: The original use case in mind was to allow for UX events to automatically make appearance changes to child SVG elements perhaps with `data-mode` attributes for example. The request was to use a single SVG to facilitate the interaction with minimal footprint. But good worked example

Answer (score 2):

Styling the SVG via a separate CSS class didn't work for me, but inline styling did:

```
&::after {
      content: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8, <svg viewBox='0 0 14 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='12px' height='18px'><path fill='rgb(13, 132, 254)' d='M2.1.1L0 2.2l8.3 8.3L9.8 12l-1.5 1.5L0 21.8l2.1 2.1L14 12z' /></svg>");
    }
```

Note: specifying the `fill` prop as a hexcode colour didn't work, even though it did if in a 'normal' SVG, that's why I converted it to RGB and styled it that way.

Comment: You need to `urlencode` the `fill` color because it's a link, mostly that means turning the `#` into `%23` and so a color of `#fafafa` would become `fill="%23fafafa"` or `fill="%23red"`

Answer (score 0):

Reading all of these answers made me come up with this nice way of dealing with SVG in SASS (.scss), which compiles CSS, for my styling theme and also get the `color` working. For my use case, I want (need) to use `content: url(..svg)` since my lib supports Font and now SVG by using `content: $my-icon;` in a pseudo `:before` that is the only thing that works with both Font/SVG.

First is to create a SASS function to deal with `urlencode` of the color (since `content: url()` needs to be encoded, `#` needs to become `%23`). For reference, I copied this function from someone else [Gist](https://gist.github.com/certainlyakey/e9c0d8f5c87ff47e3d5b). For example this will take `#fafafa` and return `%23fafafa` that I can then use in `fill` of the SVG. You could also go without it, just remember to change `#` to `%23` in the `fill` property.

```
/* sass-utilities.scss */
@function encodecolor($string) {
    @if type-of($string) == 'color' {
        $hex: str-slice(ie-hex-str($string), 4);
        $string:unquote("#{$hex}");
    }
    $string: '%23' + $string;
    @return $string;
}
```

My lib has a few SASS variables defined for theme styling so this is what I got working with both Font and/or SVG (I added `width` and `display` but it might work without too).

```
.sort-indicator-desc:before {
    content: $icon-sort-desc;
    display: inline-block;
    width: $icon-sort-font-size;    
    font-size: $icon-sort-font-size;
}
```

and finally the end user can still use it with a Font Family (like Font Awesome 4)

```
/* with a Font */
$icon-font-family:     "FontAwesome"; //  Font Awesome 4 
$icon-sort-color:      #0070d2;
$icon-sort-font-size:  13px;
$icon-sort-asc:        "\f0d8";       // unicode value of the icon
$icon-sort-desc:       "\f0d7";
// this compiles to => `content: "\f0d8";
```

or with SVG (like Font Awesome 5)

```
@import './sass-utilities'; // sass helper

/* with SVG */
$icon-sort-color:     #0070d2;
$icon-sort-font-size: 13px;
$icon-sort-asc:       url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#{encodecolor($icon-sort-color)}" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="arrowdown"><path d="M19.1 9.7c.4-.4.4-.9 0-1.3l-6.9-6.7c-.4-.4-.9-.4-1.3 0L4 8.4c-.4.4-.4.9 0 1.3l1.3 1.2c.3.4.9.4 1.3 0l2.1-2.1c.4-.4 1-.1 1 .4v12.5c0 .5.5.9 1 .9h1.8c.5 0 .9-.5.9-.9V9.2c0-.5.7-.8 1-.4l2.2 2.1c.4.4.9.4 1.3 0l1.2-1.2z"></path></svg>');
$icon-sort-desc:      url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#{encodecolor($icon-sort-color)}" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="arrowdown"><path d="M4.4 14.3c-.3.4-.3.9 0 1.3l7 6.7c.3.4.9.4 1.2 0l7-6.7c.4-.4.4-.9 0-1.3l-1.3-1.2c-.3-.4-.9-.4-1.3 0l-2.1 2.1c-.4.4-1.1.1-1.1-.4V2.3c0-.5-.4-.9-.9-.9h-1.8c-.5 0-.9.5-.9.9v12.5c0 .5-.7.8-1.1.4L7 13.1c-.4-.4-1-.4-1.3 0l-1.3 1.2z"></path></svg>');
// this compiles to => `content: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg>...');
```

So at the end, I got both the Font & SVG working with SASS variables and that is great because that means that any users of my lib ([Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid)) can still use Font Awesome 4 icons (font) while others could also use SVGs (like Font Awesome 5) without having to install the Font Family (`.eof`, `.woff`, ...) which tend to be large depending on the lib. The end result is still a compiled CSS file with `content` to load the SVG with an extra `fill` property for the SVG color.

and voilà!!! I get the best of both :)