# styling color of SVGs when used as background-image

Tags: css, svg, background-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Specify an SVG as a background image and ALSO style the SVG in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360723/specify-an-svg-as-a-background-image-and-also-style-the-svg-in-css)

I need to change the color of an SVG when used as a background-image, like so:

`background-image:inline-image("../images/svg/test.svg");`

The CSS properties need to be in an *external* stylesheet though.  I understand it can be linked from the SVG document by doing this:

`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="../../css/main.css" ?>`

And this *works* when embedding the SVG in the HTML document:

`<embed id="envelope-svg" src="../images/svg/envelope.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />`

But *doesn't* work when used as a background-image.  Is this not possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. This was discussed on this [previous question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360723/specify-an-svg-as-a-background-image-and-also-style-the-svg-in-css

Comment: ahhhh makes sense - circular reference.  thank you!