# how to change svg fill color when used as base-64 background image data?

Tags: css, svg, background, fill

I'm using SVG for a project, loaded in css like this:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/xlink%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20width%3D%2222px%22%20height%3D%2238px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2022%2038%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2022%2038%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cstyle%3E.style0%7Bfill%3A%09%23f47216%3B%7D%3C/style%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M2.643%2038c-0.64%200-1.282-0.231-1.79-0.699c-1.074-0.988-1.143-2.661-0.154-3.735l13.13-14.258L0.664%204.4%20c-0.967-1.094-0.865-2.765%200.229-3.732s2.765-0.864%203.7%200.229L19.37%2017.592c0.898%201%200.9%202.545-0.035%203.542L4.588%2037.1%20C4.067%2037.7%203.4%2038%202.6%2038z%22%20class%3D%22style0%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E');
```

I have some hover states to highlight by changing the fill color of the arrow.

For now, I'm simply applying the same svg data with the fill portion (fill%3A%09%23f47216%3B%7D%3C where **f47216** is the color) changed with the right/new color. Works pretty well. Though, I'd like to know if there's maybe some other smarter method.

Comment: The way you're doing it is the only way you can get it to work if you're set on using background-image / data uri for your svg content.  The background image is treated as just an image file, you can't change it with other CSS styles any more than you can change a PNG or JPEG file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I want to post an answer to my own question. No exactly an answer, since it doesn't imply svg as background and base64, but it's my current alternative way, much more effective if you just need mono-color icons: just use svg as css mask, and change background color. Then you can also apply transitions on mouse events. I mean something like this:

```scss
    // or -webkit prefixed
    mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M11.432 9.512a.636.636 0 0 1 0 .918L2.12 19.742a.636.636 0 0 1-.458.201.637.637 0 0 1-.46-.201l-1-.998C.068 18.609 0 18.459 0 18.285s.068-.329.199-.461l7.854-7.852L.199 2.118A.638.638 0 0 1 0 1.66c0-.174.068-.327.199-.46l1-.998A.634.634 0 0 1 1.66 0c.172 0 .325.068.458.201l9.314 9.311z"/></svg>');
    mask-size: auto 12px;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: background-color 200ms;
    background-color: #ff0000;
```

Please see this fiddle for more code and demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/o25beLqj/

Also note a couple of things:

- mask-image does not have base64 code inside. It's just preceeded by `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,`
- mask css properties are quite about the same of css background properties, take a look to docs, and you'll see you can do really a lot and they can substitute background images in a variety of use cases

Comment: not supported in Chrome (117)

Comment: Are you sure? I manage a lot of websites that use this feature, and it's pretty standard. Always remember to check caniuse, and generally speaking, I think we can all assume nowadays that we need to use Autoprefixer or the like.

Comment: Checked the demo again. It shows a blank red box. In DevTools it shows a warning near `mask-input` property with the message 'Unknown property name'. Chrome 117.

Comment: Again, in chrome it needs -webkit prefixed

Answer (score 28):

Use [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp) property of CSS.
For me I wanted to change the color of the icon to white on Hover:

```
filter: grayscale(1) brightness(2);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but `filter: invert(1);` did, just fyi for future readers who are desperate like me ;-)

Comment: `filter: invert(1);` will only work for black.  You can use `filter: brightness(0) invert(1);` for any colour.

Answer (score 19):

Or if you want to do it dynamically try :

```
var green = '3CB54A';
var red = 'ED1F24';
var svg = '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"  width="320px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 320 100" enable-background="new 0 0 320 100" xml:space="preserve"> <polygon class="mystar" fill="#'+green+'" points="134.973,14.204 143.295,31.066 161.903,33.77 148.438,46.896 151.617,65.43 134.973,56.679 118.329,65.43 121.507,46.896 108.042,33.77 126.65,31.066 "/><circle class="mycircle" fill="#'+red+'" cx="202.028" cy="58.342" r="12.26"/></svg>';      
var encoded = window.btoa(svg);
document.body.style.background = "url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+encoded+")";
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/k0cx2b04/2/)

Comment: Very useful answer.

Answer (score 16):

Base64 for that would be:

```
url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjJweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzOHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjIgMzgiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIyIDM4IiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48c3R5bGU+LnN0eWxlMHtmaWxsOgkjZjQ3MjE2O308L3N0eWxlPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yLjY0MyAzOGMtMC42NCAwLTEuMjgyLTAuMjMxLTEuNzktMC42OTljLTEuMDc0LTAuOTg4LTEuMTQzLTIuNjYxLTAuMTU0LTMuNzM1bDEzLjEzLTE0LjI1OEwwLjY2NCA0LjQgYy0wLjk2Ny0xLjA5NC0wLjg2NS0yLjc2NSAwLjIyOS0zLjczMnMyLjc2NS0wLjg2NCAzLjcgMC4yMjlMMTkuMzcgMTcuNTkyYzAuODk4IDEgMC45IDIuNTQ1LTAuMDM1IDMuNTQyTDQuNTg4IDM3LjEgQzQuMDY3IDM3LjcgMy40IDM4IDIuNiAzOHoiIGNsYXNzPSJzdHlsZTAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
```

using a tool like http://www.base64encode.org/

This doesn't answer your question directly, but it does let us do the following. We can now test to see if:

```
.icon:hover .style0 {
    fill: red;
}
```

will work, or use

```
.icon {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.icon:hover {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjJweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzOHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjIgMzgiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIyIDM4IiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48c3R5bGU+LnN0eWxlMHtmaWxsOglyZWQ7fTwvc3R5bGU+PHBhdGggZD0iTTIuNjQzIDM4Yy0wLjY0IDAtMS4yODItMC4yMzEtMS43OS0wLjY5OWMtMS4wNzQtMC45ODgtMS4xNDMtMi42NjEtMC4xNTQtMy43MzVsMTMuMTMtMTQuMjU4TDAuNjY0IDQuNCBjLTAuOTY3LTEuMDk0LTAuODY1LTIuNzY1IDAuMjI5LTMuNzMyczIuNzY1LTAuODY0IDMuNyAwLjIyOUwxOS4zNyAxNy41OTJjMC44OTggMSAwLjkgMi41NDUtMC4wMzUgMy41NDJMNC41ODggMzcuMSBDNC4wNjcgMzcuNyAzLjQgMzggMi42IDM4eiIgY2xhc3M9InN0eWxlMCIvPjwvc3ZnPg==');
}
```

which seems inefficient to me because we are forced to replicate a lot of the same information for the hover when all we want to change is the color.

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/JasonAller/GWxVa/)

Comment: It might be worth looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360723/specify-an-svg-as-a-background-image-and-also-style-the-svg-in-css

Comment: Although not precisely on point, this might be useful: http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/

Comment: Ok no, it's not possible to use style0 because there's no style0 in the final svg data. So I guess my way it's the only possible. Maybe it's not really optimized but http requests are, so it's enough for me.

Comment: to better explain: I first cleanup my svg with [this site](http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg_optimiser). Here there's still the style0 class you are writing about. But then I'll convert the optimized svg to base-64 in [this site](http://www.grumpicon.com/) and after this, style0 gets  stripped away.

Comment: This inefficiency will be effectively compressed by gzip or brotli

Comment: [https://codepen.io/yoksel/details/JDqvs/][1]
and set color that need to change

  [1]: https://codepen.io/yoksel/details/JDqvs/

Comment: first example do not work (would need to inline into HTML/DOM). Would  be cool if it did work though!