# fill color svg created with PhotoShop

Tags: css, svg

I got this icon that was created in photoshop and saved in `svg` format.

How can I change the color fill?

-- EDIT --

I made this JS bin: [https://jsbin.com/kazujoq/](https://jsbin.com/kazujoq/edit?html,css,output)

SO seems to cut out this code: xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEMAAAAeCAQAAADd02vRAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QAAKqNIzIAAAAJcEhZcwAACxIAAAsSAdLdfvwAAAAHdElNRQfhDAcMHSMd+lM1AAADSElEQVRIx83WX2iVdRzH8ZfHMzZqzrlyUVMHioPEgXqhSEkiQVfWMKErwz8oIgYRdCEYBdWVIIRZeRmRJV2MQqygCRIRhLmy0OlEbbPN3FYHmjvzHLdfF3t29uy4nc45k9b3d3O+n+fz+z7v53u+zzm/OYqJhMc9odkiizxkoepIzxrQ5zdXnXfOeSNFVZsUoUjfeu/rF4pYf2q1TU2pGEEwp6Bngzc9FX3+wzldevToN2zYg07iQ+0aNVntscg35BOHXbhf3XjAuxHqsFctn+ZBWnJZg+0+kxYEoz61tJRuTBf1zuaafaFAhZY8bb59Lkfwr0nODGOhTsGot30suF4CBiRs97sg+N7i8jGq/CDIeAEvl4EB1Y4JgpvWlovxgSB4kRlgwBaDgkGbysF4RhB8FGWvCG5MuT8pCLYUfNRNguB2oY5M9cI+7DmvW4whnaBRLS4Zvmf/PEtxS28BjFqNIKVdSkqfSy7okIpjxONRe7UZKepnaubrV+/YMNaCiS9ls2+N/kcA8dVpt+QERu8sIIyvsxaNY6RmESP4UTJImO1Y43n/Awye/TeMv+/jzaav1TQdRtph61WpUWmdQ27P4Pa3HbJOpRpV1jssfY8jOkTlj+gZDXnGem1lDmCb+rxaDc7keboCTuaJX6nAEkd0SLnsqGWY64syID43F8scdVlKhyOWoMLXeb6T8oRetdhsMKYN2Ypq3SVCdKvGVkMxbdBm1LqZ581L96NZWnDLQS0O6BFkrMbOEjF2Yo2MoMcBLQ66JUhrxv5CGHfVoVXQnZuPR1wTnEKNOyVA3DEPXwqu5eajQbegFXXuTo/RgYS0YG9sqHYIsirRXgLGOVTKCnbEau0TpCXQEXcnxP9pb2CBKvwSU39CUj26S3hRe1EvGe0fj59RZQG6YmpIesnT0akj4xhSsios913OtAKj+vGWtMqiIDLeQ79RCSu05/QmZKXwhr+iWsE3U5U4JbiiLsrmuyg4XUIf4nFacNH8KKtzJZqziUaMjcYUsVZWcNUeG+3WKRjxZJkYG4wYO1lstMdVQXbykXB6DLbJxAYoa1eZELBLNlYrY9vky4UwWOm4PsGAE1bNAAJWOWFA0Oe4lfkXxzD+AbFgJVHPGGAuAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC".

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="99" height="65" viewBox="0 0 99 65">
  <metadata><?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c140 79.160451, 2017/05/06-01:08:21        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""/>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>


<?xpacket end="w"?></metadata>
<image id="Vector_Smart_Object" data-name="Vector Smart Object" x="14" y="19" width="67" height="30" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Basically I don't think you can. Illustrator can export SVG Code rather than am embedded base-64 **image**.

Comment: But - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384934/how-to-change-svg-fill-color-when-used-as-base-64-background-image-data

Comment: I created this JS bin: https://jsbin.com/kazujoq/

Comment: That’s not really SVG it’s a raster image wrapped by SVG. There’s nothing you can really do with it.

Comment: Thanks Robert that's also my conclusion...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, if you use Illustrator to export the SVG code can then have control over its style. For instance, using `fill` to alter the color.

Here's an example in JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ks1k2us6/2/

HTML -

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon">

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
      <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="80px" height="70px" viewBox="0 0 1190.549 841.891" enable-background="new 0 0 1190.549 841.891" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
          <g>
            <path d="M356.739,473.29c-38.684,0-70.158,31.473-70.158,70.158c0,38.685,31.473,70.158,70.158,70.158
            c38.685,0,70.158-31.473,70.158-70.158C426.897,504.764,395.425,473.29,356.739,473.29z M356.739,585.543
            c-23.208,0-42.095-18.887-42.095-42.095s18.887-42.095,42.095-42.095s42.095,18.887,42.095,42.095
            S379.947,585.543,356.739,585.543z" />
          </g>
        </g>
        <g>
          <g>
            <path d="M1002.189,473.29v-84.188c0-6.033-3.859-11.408-9.598-13.316l-79.166-26.393
            c-29.816-50.498-70.803-98.557-161.376-114.426c-0.168-0.028-0.337-0.056-0.505-0.084
            c-167.271-23.124-292.852,14.606-373.477,112.182c-60.013,0.87-121.275,13.414-157.308,36.482
            c-18.661,11.954-29.732,32.763-30.771,54.905l-1.628,34.84c-7.744,0-14.031,6.286-14.031,14.031v56.125
            c0,7.745,6.287,14.031,14.031,14.031h56.126c7.787,0,14.018-6.398,14.03-14.186c0-0.071,0.016-0.14,0.016-0.226
            c0.21-54.063,44.087-97.842,98.206-97.842c54.246,0,98.22,43.975,98.22,98.22c-1.009,8.518,5.711,14.031,14.031,14.031h252.567
            c7.787,0,14.018-6.397,14.03-14.186c0-0.07,0.014-0.14,0.014-0.226c0.21-54.063,44.087-97.842,98.207-97.842
            c54.245,0,98.22,43.975,98.22,98.221c-1.01,8.518,5.711,14.03,14.031,14.03h56.125c7.744,0,14.031-6.286,14.031-14.03v-56.126
            C1016.22,479.576,1009.934,473.29,1002.189,473.29z M623.338,339.992c0,3.872-3.143,7.017-7.017,7.017H433.337
            c-6.481,0-9.429-7.971-4.645-12.334c48.689-44.382,110.609-69.766,186.914-76.514c4.11-0.365,7.731,2.946,7.731,7.072V339.992z
             M791.912,340.062c-0.043,3.844-3.172,6.945-7.017,6.945H658.416c-3.872,0-7.016-3.143-7.016-7.017v-76.612
            c0-3.887,3.101-7.085,6.973-7.085c27.979-0.028,57.586,2.006,89.059,6.357c14.986,2.638,28.343,6.258,40.494,10.706
            c2.792,1.024,4.574,3.733,4.547,6.708L791.912,340.062z M865.143,347.007h-38.151c-3.9,0-7.057-3.186-7.016-7.086l0.364-38.024
            c0.057-5.794,6.665-8.938,11.338-5.515c15.169,11.084,27.782,24.289,39.021,39.275
            C874.206,340.327,870.979,347.007,865.143,347.007z" />
          </g>
        </g>
        <g>
          <g>
            <path d="M833.811,473.29c-38.685,0-70.158,31.473-70.158,70.158c0,38.685,31.473,70.158,70.158,70.158
            c38.684,0,70.158-31.473,70.158-70.158C903.967,504.764,872.494,473.29,833.811,473.29z M833.811,585.543
            c-23.208,0-42.095-18.887-42.095-42.095s18.887-42.095,42.095-42.095s42.095,18.887,42.095,42.095
            S857.019,585.543,833.811,585.543z" />
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>


  </div>
  <h1>Cars</h1>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

svg {
  fill: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I need to find out how to use the SVG icon in my react component. Maybe you know the answer to that as well? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47699733/inline-svg-in-react-16

Comment: @olefrank Sorry I have not had much interaction with React, any Vue issues though hit me up. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

The bitmap converted to svg can not be stylized using the usual methods: `fill: orange;`
But you can change its color entirely using [`SVG filters`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters)

[Browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20filter) `SVG filter`

To fill the color I will use  filter primitive `feColorMatrix`

This filter applies a matrix transformation:

[image]

The theory looks frightening, but in reality it is quite easy to use filters in practice.

To fill in red, I will use the following matrix:

```
    <filter id="RedFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                    values="0 0 0 1 0
                            0 0 0 0 0
                            0 0 0 0 0
                            0 0 0 1 0
                    "/> 
   </filter>
```

`"1"` is in the first line, which is responsible for the red color, in the fourth line - the alpha channel responsible for transparency.

Below is the full code of filling in red:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="99" height="65" viewBox="0 0 99 65"
> 

  <defs>
 <filter id="RedFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
 


   <image   id="Vector_Smart_Object"   x="14" y="19" width="67" height="30" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEMAAAAeCAQAAADd02vRAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QAAKqNIzIAAAAJcEhZcwAACxIAAAsSAdLdfvwAAAAHdElNRQfhDAcMHSMd+lM1AAADSElEQVRIx83WX2iVdRzH8ZfHMzZqzrlyUVMHioPEgXqhSEkiQVfWMKErwz8oIgYRdCEYBdWVIIRZeRmRJV2MQqygCRIRhLmy0OlEbbPN3FYHmjvzHLdfF3t29uy4nc45k9b3d3O+n+fz+z7v53u+zzm/OYqJhMc9odkiizxkoepIzxrQ5zdXnXfOeSNFVZsUoUjfeu/rF4pYf2q1TU2pGEEwp6Bngzc9FX3+wzldevToN2zYg07iQ+0aNVntscg35BOHXbhf3XjAuxHqsFctn+ZBWnJZg+0+kxYEoz61tJRuTBf1zuaafaFAhZY8bb59Lkfwr0nODGOhTsGot30suF4CBiRs97sg+N7i8jGq/CDIeAEvl4EB1Y4JgpvWlovxgSB4kRlgwBaDgkGbysF4RhB8FGWvCG5MuT8pCLYUfNRNguB2oY5M9cI+7DmvW4whnaBRLS4Zvmf/PEtxS28BjFqNIKVdSkqfSy7okIpjxONRe7UZKepnaubrV+/YMNaCiS9ls2+N/kcA8dVpt+QERu8sIIyvsxaNY6RmESP4UTJImO1Y43n/Awye/TeMv+/jzaav1TQdRtph61WpUWmdQ27P4Pa3HbJOpRpV1jssfY8jOkTlj+gZDXnGem1lDmCb+rxaDc7keboCTuaJX6nAEkd0SLnsqGWY64syID43F8scdVlKhyOWoMLXeb6T8oRetdhsMKYN2Ypq3SVCdKvGVkMxbdBm1LqZ581L96NZWnDLQS0O6BFkrMbOEjF2Yo2MoMcBLQ66JUhrxv5CGHfVoVXQnZuPR1wTnEKNOyVA3DEPXwqu5eajQbegFXXuTo/RgYS0YG9sqHYIsirRXgLGOVTKCnbEau0TpCXQEXcnxP9pb2CBKvwSU39CUj26S3hRe1EvGe0fj59RZQG6YmpIesnT0akj4xhSsios913OtAKj+vGWtMqiIDLeQ79RCSu05/QmZKXwhr+iWsE3U5U4JbiiLsrmuyg4XUIf4nFacNH8KKtzJZqziUaMjcYUsVZWcNUeG+3WKRjxZJkYG4wYO1lstMdVQXbykXB6DLbJxAYoa1eZELBLNlYrY9vky4UwWOm4PsGAE1bNAAJWOWFA0Oe4lfkXxzD+AbFgJVHPGGAuAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" /> 
   </defs> 
   <use xlink:href="#Vector_Smart_Object" filter="url(#RedFilter)" ></use>
   
   
</svg>
```

For filling with other colors, minor changes in the matrix will be required. The green color is "1" in the second line, the rest of the line, except for the alpha channel is zeros.

In the example below, the `<use>` command is used, which makes it possible to color the clones in different colors by applying a filter with different matrix formulas to them.

```
             <use xlink:href="#Vector_Smart_Object" x="0" y="0"  filter="url(#RedFilter)" ></use> 
             <use xlink:href="#Vector_Smart_Object" x="100" y="0" filter="url(#GreenFilter)" ></use> 
             <use xlink:href="#Vector_Smart_Object" x="200" y="0" filter="url(#BlueFilter)" ></use>
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="65" viewBox="0 0 400 65"
> 

  <defs>
 <filter id="RedFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
 <filter id="GreenFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
 
 <filter id="BlueFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
 


   <image   id="Vector_Smart_Object"   x="14" y="19" width="67" height="30" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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" /> 
   </defs> 
   <use xlink:href="#Vector_Smart_Object" x="0" y="0"  filter="url(#RedFilter)" ></use> 
   <use xlink:href="#Vector_Smart_Object" x="100" y="0" filter="url(#GreenFilter)" ></use> 
    <use xlink:href="#Vector_Smart_Object" x="200" y="0" filter="url(#BlueFilter)" ></use>
   
   
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a shape of the icon if you haven't already.  Then, instead of exporting the SVG file via "Export As.." in the File menu, right click on the shape layer, and click "Copy SVG".  Paste this into a blank document and save it as a .svg file.  It will have a fill property.