# Inline SVG in react 16

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I have a SVG file that I want to use as an icon in my react component.

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 409.6 405.76"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;}.cls-2{clip-path:url(#clip-path);}</style><clipPath id="clip-path" transform="translate(-478 -181.08)"><rect class="cls-1" x="478" y="181" width="409.92" height="406.8"/></clipPath></defs><title>test</title><g class="cls-2"><path class="ofj" d="M682.8,396.06c50.72,0,91.84-48.13,91.84-107.49,0-82.33-41.12-107.49-91.84-107.49S591,206.24,591,288.57c0,59.36,41.12,107.49,91.84,107.49Zm0,0" transform="translate(-478 -181.08)"/><path d="M885.6,554.28,839.27,449.9a23.3,23.3,0,0,0-10.48-11.15l-71.91-37.43a4.66,4.66,0,0,0-4.93.41,113.41,113.41,0,0,1-138.3,0,4.67,4.67,0,0,0-4.94-.41l-71.9,37.43a23.24,23.24,0,0,0-10.47,11.15L480,554.28a23.16,23.16,0,0,0,21.18,32.56H864.42a23.17,23.17,0,0,0,21.18-32.56Zm0,0" transform="translate(-478 -181.08)"/></g></svg>
```

I want to be able to change the fill color dynamically. I've read that it's best to use SVG 'inline' and I tried to reference it with a `<use>` but it does not work (it's not showing...)

```
<svg className="icon-avator">
  <use xlinkHref="./assets/avatar.svg" />
</svg>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: <use> points to a fragment not an entire file. <image> is for complete files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

React JSX can produce SVG, the same way it does with HTML. Write the SVG as the component's "markup", and use props to control the `fill` attribute (you can also change the style):

```js
const Icon = ({ fill }) => (
  <svg viewBox="0 0 409.6 405.76" fill={ fill }>
      <path d="M682.8,396.06c50.72,0,91.84-48.13,91.84-107.49,0-82.33-41.12-107.49-91.84-107.49S591,206.24,591,288.57c0,59.36,41.12,107.49,91.84,107.49Zm0,0" transform="translate(-478 -181.08)"/>
      <path d="M885.6,554.28,839.27,449.9a23.3,23.3,0,0,0-10.48-11.15l-71.91-37.43a4.66,4.66,0,0,0-4.93.41,113.41,113.41,0,0,1-138.3,0,4.67,4.67,0,0,0-4.94-.41l-71.9,37.43a23.24,23.24,0,0,0-10.47,11.15L480,554.28a23.16,23.16,0,0,0,21.18,32.56H864.42a23.17,23.17,0,0,0,21.18-32.56Zm0,0" transform="translate(-478 -181.08)"/>
  </svg>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Icon fill="red" />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Cool thanks :) Do you then know what's the best way to make the Icon component dynamic to be able to show different SVG markup? Maybe a trivial question, but my brain is dead right now!!

Comment: Each symbol can be a component, and you can have SymbolA, SymbolB, etc.. Now you can wrap them with a generic Icon component that selects the symbol according to a property.

Comment: To make it cleaner you could remove the `<title>` tag, take both `<path>`s out of `<g>` and delete it, remove `fill` from `<path>`s and set it inside `<svg>` :)

Comment: Instead of hard coding the svg markup, would it be possible to import or otherwise load the markup from a svg file?

Comment: @olefrank - you can always load the svg as an image. Another option is to use [react-svg-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-loader) - A loader for webpack, rollup, babel that loads svg as a React Component.

Answer (score 2):

For people landing on this page, there is also a webpack loader which generates React components from SVG files. [react-svg-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-loader)

If you are using create-react-app, you might want to eject for now. But know this; there are discussions about integrating such a loader in CRA and [it's on the 2.0.0 roadmap apparently](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3856)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a npm package that converts all svg elements to the correct JSX incase anyone else came here and stumbled with a similar problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-svg-react

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to not use an external source, so instead of doing

```html
<use href="/path/to/icon.svg" />
```

create a sprite with symbols (e.g. with https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-sprite) like that:

```html
<svg ...>
  // icon contents here, except `svg` tag became `symbol` tag
  <symbol id="icon-id-inside-the-sprite" ...>
    // ...
  </symbol>
  // may be add more icons
</svg>
```

inline it into your HTML somewhere and hide with `display: none` style, then use it like

```html
<use href="#icon-id-inside-the-sprite" />
```

Now you should be able to target its inner classes from your outside CSS.