# Stylizing SVG element using ReactJS with CSS-Modules

Tags: javascript, css, svg, reactjs, css-modules

I have an app which is worked on `ReactJS`. I'm using [CSS-Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) for inline styles. I have a separate `svg` file with icon and I want to stylize it in my component's `css` file.

Here is an icon **MyComponent/add.svg** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 533.333 533.333" style="enable-background:new 0 0 533.333 533.333;" xml:space="preserve;">
<g>
    <path d="M516.667,200H333.333V16.667C333.333,7.462,325.871,0,316.667,0h-100C207.462,0,200,7.462,200,16.667V200H16.667   C7.462,200,0,207.462,0,216.667v100c0,9.204,7.462,16.666,16.667,16.666H200v183.334c0,9.204,7.462,16.666,16.667,16.666h100   c9.204,0,16.667-7.462,16.667-16.666V333.333h183.333c9.204,0,16.667-7.462,16.667-16.666v-100   C533.333,207.462,525.871,200,516.667,200z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Here is my **MyComponent/MyComponent.css**

```
.iconButton {

}

.icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}


.iconAdd {
  composes: icon;
  background: url('./add.svg');
}
```

And it's a piece of code from my **MyComponent/MyComponent.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './MyComponent.css';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={ styles.iconButton }>
                <div className={ styles.iconAdd }></div>
                <div>add</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It works OK. But I've faced the issue when I try to apply style for `svg` item (for example: fill) it doesn't work and nothing changes.

Should you recommend a way to implement this case?

Thanks for watching this question.

Comment: is it deployed anywhere?

Comment: You can't apply styles to `SVG` element which is used as a background image. Not without some complex string manipulation with help of `SASS`, which I described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360723/specify-an-svg-as-a-background-image-and-also-style-the-svg-in-css/33778133#33778133). To have more control over your `SVG` (with `CSS`), inline it first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was need to somehow manipulate with `SVG` icons in my app. That's why I've made use of @robjez advice and inline them first.

I've implemented a few `React` components for every icon that I need to stylize. A little sample is below:

```
export default class FolderIcon extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <svg viewBox="0 0 475.082 475.082">
                <g>
                    <path d="M456.239,128.475c-12.56-12.562-27.597-18.842-45.11-18.842h-191.86v-9.136c0-17.511-6.283-32.548-18.843-45.107   c-12.562-12.562-27.6-18.846-45.111-18.846H63.953c-17.515,0-32.551,6.283-45.111,18.846C6.28,67.949,0,82.986,0,100.497v274.088   c0,17.508,6.28,32.545,18.842,45.104c12.562,12.565,27.6,18.849,45.111,18.849h347.175c17.514,0,32.551-6.283,45.11-18.849   c12.566-12.56,18.843-27.597,18.843-45.104V173.59C475.082,156.078,468.805,141.042,456.239,128.475z" />
                </g>
            </svg>
        );
    }
}
```

After that I have a possibility to use [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) and stylize `SVG` from code of a `Component`.

```
.icon svg {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
}
```

That's the sample of using:

```
import FolderIcon from '../FolderIcon.jsx';
import styles from './Folder.css';

export default class Folder extends Component {
    render() {
        return <FolderIcon className={styles.icon} />;
    }
}
```