# Firefox scales SVG in a fit-content container too large

Tags: css, svg, width

I have a container with two elements inside. A Link tag and an inline svg.

My plan is to set the width of the container to the maximum width of its children, which I assume should be the content of the link tag with its padding.

Since the svg has no width defined and only uses a viewBox, I would assume the browser to scale the svg to the width of its parent container.

All browser except firefox are behaving like that. I don't understand why Firefox is stretching the container to 100% of the usable space, even larger than the viewbox of the svg.

```css
div {
  width: fit-content;
  background: #344566;
}

a {
  padding: 0 4rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

svg {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">This is a link</a>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 492.004 492.004" style="enable-background:new 0 0 492.004 492.004" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M484.14 226.886 306.46 49.202c-5.072-5.072-11.832-7.856-19.04-7.856-7.216 0-13.972 2.788-19.044 7.856l-16.132 16.136c-5.068 5.064-7.86 11.828-7.86 19.04 0 7.208 2.792 14.2 7.86 19.264L355.9 207.526H26.58C11.732 207.526 0 219.15 0 234.002v22.812c0 14.852 11.732 27.648 26.58 27.648h330.496L252.248 388.926c-5.068 5.072-7.86 11.652-7.86 18.864 0 7.204 2.792 13.88 7.86 18.948l16.132 16.084c5.072 5.072 11.828 7.836 19.044 7.836 7.208 0 13.968-2.8 19.04-7.872l177.68-177.68c5.084-5.088 7.88-11.88 7.86-19.1.016-7.244-2.776-14.04-7.864-19.12z"/></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the SVG to be a background image of the link. This will make the link text control the size of the box. To make space for the background I added a block (`a:after`) after the link that has a padding of 100%. This is sometimes used for making a square, but is also useful in this situation.

```css
div {
  width: fit-content;
  background: #344566;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 4rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 492.004 492.004" style="enable-background:new 0 0 492.004 492.004;fill:white" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M484.14 226.886 306.46 49.202c-5.072-5.072-11.832-7.856-19.04-7.856-7.216 0-13.972 2.788-19.044 7.856l-16.132 16.136c-5.068 5.064-7.86 11.828-7.86 19.04 0 7.208 2.792 14.2 7.86 19.264L355.9 207.526H26.58C11.732 207.526 0 219.15 0 234.002v22.812c0 14.852 11.732 27.648 26.58 27.648h330.496L252.248 388.926c-5.068 5.072-7.86 11.652-7.86 18.864 0 7.204 2.792 13.88 7.86 18.948l16.132 16.084c5.072 5.072 11.828 7.836 19.044 7.836 7.208 0 13.968-2.8 19.04-7.872l177.68-177.68c5.084-5.088 7.88-11.88 7.86-19.1.016-7.244-2.776-14.04-7.864-19.12z"/></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 1rem;
  background-size: contain;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">This is a link</a>
</div>
```

### Update

OP asks if the color of the background can be changed on hover. It cannot: [Specify an SVG as a background image and ALSO style the SVG in CSS? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7361787/322084). But in this case the SVG can be used as a [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) on the element -- or like in this case -- on the after pseudo element. The SVG is masking the background-color -- and this can be changed on hover. Here I's using the [currentColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentcolor_keyword) value.

```css
div {
  width: fit-content;
  background: #344566;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 4rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background-color: currentColor;
  mask: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 492.004 492.004" style="enable-background:new 0 0 492.004 492.004;fill:white" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M484.14 226.886 306.46 49.202c-5.072-5.072-11.832-7.856-19.04-7.856-7.216 0-13.972 2.788-19.044 7.856l-16.132 16.136c-5.068 5.064-7.86 11.828-7.86 19.04 0 7.208 2.792 14.2 7.86 19.264L355.9 207.526H26.58C11.732 207.526 0 219.15 0 234.002v22.812c0 14.852 11.732 27.648 26.58 27.648h330.496L252.248 388.926c-5.068 5.072-7.86 11.652-7.86 18.864 0 7.204 2.792 13.88 7.86 18.948l16.132 16.084c5.072 5.072 11.828 7.836 19.044 7.836 7.208 0 13.968-2.8 19.04-7.872l177.68-177.68c5.084-5.088 7.88-11.88 7.86-19.1.016-7.244-2.776-14.04-7.864-19.12z"/></svg>');
}

a:hover {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">This is a link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way with this solution to edit for example the fill value of the svg on hover? I would like to alter some paths color and transformation and I'm not sure, if this is even possible when using background image.

Comment: @MistaK. Yes, that is a problem. I updated my answer with a second example whee I use the SVG as a mask.